# How to center text always relative of div size with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have created a div box with flexbox.
This box has a min-height:
https://jsfiddle.net/m267w3ku/1/

Code:

```
<section id="welcome-section">
      <h1>Hey, I am Someone!</h1>
</section>


#welcome-section{
  background-color:#5998ff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:400px;
  width:100%;
}
```

**What I have**: Text is in center, box has min-height of 400px.

**Problem** Text does not always stay center when minimizing the browser

**What I want** Text always stay center relative of the box size even when minimizing browser

When minimizing browser now, this happens eventually:
[image]

Comment: The text is staying vertically centered relative to the box size for me. In what scenario it doesn't work like that for you?

Comment: It is centered in my browser... Do you mean that it doesn't look centered because part of the element is getting cut off?

Comment: or you mean you want the blue box to have 100% of the window height?

Comment: Please check updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is staying vertically centered relative to the box size for me. In what scenario it doesn't work like that for you?

If what you want is the blue box to be 100% of the window height try:

`height: 100vh;`

Comment: vh works, it keeps the text always visible (in center) even when minimizing the browser

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `text-align: center`: https://jsfiddle.net/82x7vm9h/

Comment: What's the max-height setting for?

Comment: No more height, you can try without it

Comment: Sorry this is not what i needed

Comment: What happen if you put `max-height: 100% ` ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#welcome-section {
  background-color: #5998ff;
  display: flex;
  
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hey, I am Someone!</h1>
</section>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: just remove the width: 100wh and i hope it will work than. i just updated my answer